# AWSのEC2インスタンスを別VPCに移動したい。

Tags: aws, vpc, amazon-ec2

SGやVPCの見直しを行っておりまして、
EC2のインスタンスを別VPCに移動させたいと考えています。

調べたところ↓のスレッドで
元のVPCのEC2でマウントされていたEBSをデタッチした後に、
移転先のVPCでEC2を立ち上げアタッチしなおしたところ、
インスタンスの状態がrunnningで動かなくなりました。
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103204

そこで質問なのですが、上記の方法で、
EBSだけを切り離して、別のVPCのEC2のインスタンスにマウントすることは可能でしょうか？

また、別の良いやり方があれば教えて頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既存のインスタンスからAMIを作って 新しいVPC上でAMIから Launch すればどうでしょうか。

Comment: やはりAMIを作成する方法が一番楽なんでしょうか。

Comment: @Kun Ns EBSのデタッチとアタッチは仮想化タイプやKernel ID デバイスファイル名などの設定に気をつけないと起動できなくなるので 個人的には AMI化する よりハマりやすい気がしてます。